# Meteor and SyncedCron the tasks are firing on all days. The times are working fine

Tags: javascript, meteor

the goal of this is to have people come in and out of a schedule that i have saved on another page. I do not understand why it is activating for everyone on every day. The time is working for everyone but there are some days that it should not be working.  The first bit of code is the template that i have to pull from. the second is me pulling from this and trying to make a SyncedCron from it.

```
name: name,
StartTime: startT,
EndTime: endT,
Monday: Monday,
Tuesday: Tuesday,
Wednesday: Wednesday,
Thursday: Thursday,
Friday: Friday,
Saturday: Saturday,
Sunday: Sunday,
queue: false,
status: "Working",
weight: 1,
OOTO: false,
Lunch: false
```

​

```
updateCron: function() {
SyncedCron.stop();
var temp = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday"
];

temp.forEach(function(day) {
  var temp = {};
  // temp[day] = false;

  _Techs.find(temp).forEach(function(tech) {


    if (tech.startTime != "" && tech[day]) {
      var startTimeTemp = "at " + tech.StartTime + " every " + day;
      var endTimeTemp = "at " + tech.EndTime + " every " + day;
      SyncedCron.add({name: tech.name + " Work Start " + day,
      schedule: function(parser) {return parser.text(startTimeTemp);},
        job: function() {_Techs.update({_id: tech._id}, {$set: {
              queue: true,
              totaltickets: 0,
              dispatched: false,
              timesincelast: new Date(),
              status: "Working"
            }
          });
          // console.log(tech.name + " Entered Queue");
          return "Worked";
        }
      });
    };

    if (tech.endTime != "" && tech[day]) {
      var startTimeTemp = "at " + tech.StartTime + " every " + day;
      var endTimeTemp = "at " + tech.EndTime + " every " + day;
      SyncedCron.add({
        name: tech.name + ' Work End Time for ' + day,
        schedule: function(parser) {
          return parser.text(endTimeTemp);
        },
        job: function() {
          _Techs.update({
            _id: tech._id
          }, {
            $set: {
              queue: false,
              totaltickets: 0,
              dispatched: false,
              timesincelast: new Date(),
              status: "Working"
            }
          });
          // console.log(tech.name + " Left Queue");
          return "Worked";
        }
      });
  };
  });
});
SyncedCron.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like i found out what the problem was. I was using `"every"` and i should have been using `"on"`. this is what that one line looks like now.

`var startTimeTemp = "at " + tech.StartTime + " on " + day;`

It used to look like this

`var startTimeTemp = "at " + tech.StartTime + " every " + day;`